# RPC failed; HTTP 400 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 400 Bad Request

Tags: git, version-control, gitlab, git-push

I am trying to push my code from an old repository to a new repository as my old repository seems to be currupted somehow

getting following error:

```
Counting objects: 19815, done.
Compressing objects: 100% (5264/5264), done.
Writing objects: 100% (19815/19815), 44.91 MiB | 134.87 MiB/s, done.
Total 19815 (delta 14641), reused 19405 (delta 14283)
error: RPC failed; HTTP 400 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 400 Bad Request
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

I tried `git config http.postBuffer 524288000` but it did not help I even tried to do `git push --force origin` and `git push --all` but am receiving same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced the same error.
I had a task to move from one server to another (**TFS** to **Azure**), all the repositories, except one, were easily moved using [THIS](https://makandracards.com/makandra/16059-duplicate-a-git-repository-with-all-branches-and-tags) procedure.
One repository, when trying to make a **PUSH**, threw out such an error.
There are about 15 branches in this repository.
I decided to transfer one branch at a time, using `git push url://to/new/repository.git branch-to-move:new-branch-name`.
When I applied this option to the **master** branch, I got the same error.
Then I transferred all other branches (there were no problems with them).
After that, the **master** branch migrated without problems.

Answer (score 2):

You may try to use the upstream (tracking) reference in your git command, by adding the [`-u`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt--u) option.

```
git push -u origin master
```

Answer (score 1):

It happened to me that it did not work for one internet connection (ZTE WLAN router). After switching to another one it worked. Specifying the user did not help in the first case. Unfortunately, I don't know how to debug the actual issue, but maybe this information helps someone else.

```
$ git push
Enumerating objects: 34, done.
Counting objects: 100% (34/34), done.
Delta compression using up to 16 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (21/21), done.
Writing objects: 100% (21/21), 3.11 KiB | 52.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 21 (delta 16), reused 0 (delta 0)
error: RPC failed; HTTP 400 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 400
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

Comment: Ha! Same here, I've switched from Huawei router to ZTE router and the problem started to appear.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced same error this morning. Upgrading to newer version (2.29.2.windows.2) fixed the issue for me.
Sorry, I didn't have time to take git trace or further investigate this issue. Thus just sharing my experience.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this. But please notice that it was better to write this as a comment instead of an answer according to the type of information you've provide.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! This was my first time posting to SO, and I think I messed up... I will keep in mind to the deference b/w comments and solutions. Please let me know if it's better to delete this solution and write as comment instead.