Unable to clone a specific Github repository
I am trying to build and test the TEASER++ project (https://github.com/MIT-SPARK/TEASER-plusplus) and use Python bindings with it (pybind11).
During the building process, everything is cloned/downloaded without any problems, except for the pybind11 (https://github.com/pybind/pybind11). At this step the process stalls, since the repository cannot be cloned:
Cloning into 'pybind11-src'...
error: RPC failed; HTTP 400 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 400
fatal: error reading section header 'shallow-info'
Cloning into 'pybind11-src'...
error: RPC failed; HTTP 400 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 400
fatal: error reading section header 'shallow-info'
Cloning into 'pybind11-src'...
error: RPC failed; HTTP 400 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 400
fatal: error reading section header 'shallow-info'
-- Had to git clone more than once:
          3 times.
CMake Error at pybind11-download/pmc-prefix/tmp/pmc-gitclone.cmake:31 (message):
  Failed to clone repository: 'https://github.com/pybind/pybind11.git'


gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/pmc.dir/build.make:99: pmc-prefix/src/pmc-stamp/pmc-download] Error 1
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:83: CMakeFiles/pmc.dir/all] Error 2
gmake: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:141 (add_subdirectory):
  add_subdirectory given source
  "/home/klift/dev/experiments/TEASER-plusplus/build/pybind11-src" which is
  not an existing directory.


-- TEASER++ Python binding will be built.
CMake Error at python/CMakeLists.txt:5 (pybind11_add_module):
  Unknown CMake command "pybind11_add_module".


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

I tried to separately clone the repository, since I assumed that there might be problems with the CMAKE. However, just trying to clone the repo with
git clone https://github.com/pybind/pybind11

results in the following error
Cloning into 'pybind11'...
error: RPC failed; HTTP 400 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 400
fatal: error reading section header 'shallow-info'

I tried updating git and also tried cloning other repositories - no issues were found there.

Tried using ssh to clone?

git clone https://github.com/pybind/pybind11 works for me

Maybe relevant https://stackoverflow.com/a/65070253/1725151

Although you are doing full clone with git clone, it is interesting that it yields an error related to the shallow clone (which truncates some commit history in order to reduce data cloned). This may be a network or firewall issue. Please try disabling shallow clone with --depth. git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/pybind/pybind11.git

@DilliBabuS, no I have not tried that, since the project installation is based on the cmake and I am not sure how to reconfigure it to use the ssh instead of https. It is quite a weak area for me (configuring large cmake files), so for now I tried to skip altering it. But thank you for the idea!

@MuratK. and Guildenstern, thank you for your replies as well! They both contain overlapping solutions. In the end, I used the --depth flag and cloning like that worked well. I still struggled to fix it in the cmake files, though. However, today I am working from the other office and the normal clone command (without the --depth flag) worked as well, so I think the theory that the issue was caused by the VPN/Firewall is valid

Duplicate issue - try using this -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62753648/rpc-failed-http-400-curl-22-the-requested-url-returned-error-400-bad-request
